# R - "max subgraphs" in graph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to identify the maximum subgraphs in a given graph

for example , for these graph :
[image]

and this code :

```
    library("igraph")        
    from <- c(1,2,3,3,6,6,8,9)
    to <- c(2,3,4,5,7,8,6,10)
    edges = data.frame(from,to)
    g<- graph_from_data_frame(edges,directed=FALSE)
    plot(g)

    clc <- max_cliques(g, min=3)
    clc
```

max cliques with min=3 gives me **empty list**...

the result I want to get (with min=3)  is :

(1,2,3,4,5)
(6,7,8)

Comment: Do you know the definition of clique ? It's a subgraph in which for each couple of nodes, there's an arc between them... of course (1,2,3,4,5) and (6,7,8) are not cliques... they are just connected components...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are not cliques, but connected components.

In your graph, the cliques (*complete* subgraphs) are of size 2 or less, so the function `max_cliques` will not return you anything if you set the minimal size to 3.

On the other hand, you can use the function `clusters` to find the largest connected components of your graph.

```
cl <- clusters(g)
me <- which(cl$csize >= 3)
res <- split(names(cl$membership), cl$membership)[me]
res
$`1`
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"

$`2`
[1] "6" "8" "7"
```